# VFP using VFP2EXCEL - Is there a way to easily trim character fields that are sent to Excel

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am using Cetin Basoz's VFP2Excel to copy/export a subset of data created by a VFP SQL statement to Excel.

What I am trying to figure out: is there a way to TRIM the character fields that are sent to Excel this way?

If I have a sample table (company.dbf) with 1 field c_company C(40) and 3 entries in the table like so:

```
IBM
Microsoft
Some Big Long Company Name Here
```

When I use the VFP command: COPY TO example.xls TYPE XL5

It appears that the data exported to Excel with the command above is trimmed.  I do not have do anything additional to trim the character fields.  The IBM entry is "IBM" with no trailing spaces.  Same with Microsoft.

However, when I export the same data using VFP2Excel, all the entries have trailing spaces up to the length of the field.

```
"IBM                                     "
"Microsoft                               "
"Some Big Long Company Name Here         "
```

Is there an easy way to trim the trailing spaces from character fields exporting data using VFP2Excel?  I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out.  If not, is there a quick and easy way to trim all of my character fields once it gets into Excel from VFP?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know an easy way for that. VFP2Excel basically sends to Excel whatever selected by an SQL and it is VFP's nature to have char fields with trailing spaces. VFP also have a (fake) varchar data type which doesn't have trailing blanks, that should work out of the box.

Although it is not easy (meaning you have to do some more typing), you can trim your char fields and make them varchar fields in your SQL (or use CursorAdapter with a CursorSchema where those fields are varchar, but that is a longer path).

Below is a simple sample (I have posted many variations of VFP2Excel, yours might be a different one but the end result is same - note that all the work is done in the SQL that selects the data, VFP2Excel itself is unmodified):

```
SELECT CAST(TRIM(first_name) as varchar(20)) as firstName, CAST(trim(last_name) as Varchar(20)) as lastName,notes ;
  from (_Samples+"data\employee") ;
  into cursor crsSample ;
  nofilter
  
Local oExcel
oExcel = Createobject("Excel.Application")
With oExcel
  .Workbooks.Add
  .Visible = .T.
  VFP2Excel('crsSample', ;
    .ActiveWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), 'First Name,Last Name,Notes of employee' ) && To sheet1, start at A1
Endwith


Procedure VFP2Excel
Lparameters tcCursorName, toRange, tcHeaders, tnPrefferredWidthForMemo
* tcCursorName
* toRange
* tcHeaders: Optional. Defaults to field headers
* tnPrefferredWidthForMemo: Optional. Default 80
* Function VFP2Excel
tcCursorName = Evl(m.tcCursorName,Alias())
tnPrefferredWidthForMemo = Evl(m.tnPrefferredWidthForMemo,80)
Local loConn As AdoDB.Connection, loRS As AdoDB.Recordset,;
  lcTemp,lcTempDb, oExcel,ix, lcFieldName, lcHeaders

lnSelect = Select()
lcTemp   = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.dbf',Sys(2023))
lcTempDb = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.dbc',Sys(2023))

Create Database (m.lcTempDb)
Select * From (m.tcCursorName) Into Table (m.lcTemp) Database (m.lcTempDb)

Local Array aMemo[1], aDateTime[Fcount()]
Local nMemoCount
Store 0 to m.nMemoCount
lcHeaders = ''
For ix = 1 To Fcount()
  lcFieldName = Field(m.ix)
  If Type(Field(m.ix))='M'
    nMemoCount = m.nMemoCount + 1
    Dimension aMemo[m.nMemoCount]
    aMemo[m.nMemoCount] = m.ix
    Replace All &lcFieldName With Chrtran(&lcFieldName,Chr(13)+Chr(10),Chr(10))
  EndIf
  aDateTime[m.ix] = (Type(Field(m.ix))='T')
  lcHeaders = m.lcHeaders + Iif(Empty(m.lcHeaders),'',',')+Proper(m.lcFieldName)
Endfor
tcHeaders = Evl(m.tcHeaders,m.lcHeaders)

Use In (Juststem(m.lcTemp))
Close Databases
Set Database To

loStream = Createobject('AdoDb.Stream')
loConn = Createobject('ADODB.Connection')
loRS = Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
loConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source="+m.lcTempDb
loConn.Open()
loRS = loConn.Execute("select * from "+m.lcTemp)
loRS.Save( loStream )
loRS.Close
loConn.Close
Erase (m.lcTemp)

* Use first row for headers
Local Array aHeader[1]

loRS.Open( loStream )
toRange.Offset(1,0).CopyFromRecordSet( loRS )  && Copy data starting from headerrow + 1

Set Safety Off
Delete Database (m.lcTempDb) Deletetables

Select (m.lnSelect)

For ix=1 To Iif( !Empty(m.tcHeaders), ;
    ALINES(aHeader, m.tcHeaders,1,','), ;
    loRS.Fields.Count )
  toRange.Offset(0,m.ix-1).Value = ;
    Iif( !Empty(m.tcHeaders), ;
    aHeader[m.ix], ;
    Proper(loRS.Fields(m.ix-1).Name) )
  toRange.Offset(0,m.ix-1).Font.Bold = .T.
EndFor

For ix=1 to Alen(aDateTime)
    If (aDateTime[m.ix])
        toRange.WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns(m.ix).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    endif
endfor

#Define xlJustify                                         -4130
#Define xlTop                                             -4160
* This part is cosmetic
toRange.WorkSheet.Activate
With toRange.WorkSheet.UsedRange
  .VerticalAlignment = xlTop && set all to top
  For ix=1 To m.nMemoCount
    With .Columns(aMemo[m.ix])
      .ColumnWidth = m.tnPrefferredWidthForMemo && 80 chars width
      .WrapText = .T.
    Endwith
  Endfor
  .Columns.AutoFit
  .Rows.AutoFit
Endwith
```